# Proof that even if you change the vector spaces of a transformation, the rank remains the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb Q,$ and let $T: \mathbb Q^n → \mathbb Q^m$ be the linear transformation $T(x) = Ax.$ We may also regard the matrix $A$ as having entries in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C.$ Let $T':\mathbb R^n → \mathbb R^m$ and $T'': \mathbb C^n → \mathbb C^m$ be the corresponding linear transformations $T'(x) = Ax,$ and $T''(x) = Ax.$ Show that rank($T$) = rank($T'$) = rank($T''$).

The rank of $T$ is dim(im($T$)). As we have that $\dim(\mathbb Q^m)=\dim(\mathbb R^m)=\dim(\mathbb C^m)= m$, can we directly conclude? I'm unsure whether or not we have that im($T$) $= \mathbb Q^m.$ Can the image be smaller just like with functions?  Therefore, if $A$ stays the same, then the im($T$)=im($T'$)=im($T''$) no matter the vector spaces where you apply the transformation. I am just really confused and don't know how to start this proof. I can sense why this is true but don't really know how to prove it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that the rank is the dimension of the range, but it is also the maximal number of linearly independent columns of $A.$ Let's say the rank is $r$.  That means that there is a set of columns $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_r$ such that the only solution to $$a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_rX_2=0\tag 1$$ is $a_1=a_2=\cdots =a_r=0.$  Now the question is, if we allow the $a_i$ to be elements of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ might we not be able to find a nonzero solution?  After all, we have a lot more numbers to choose from.

Think about solving the system of equations (1).  The $a_i$ are the unknowns, and the coefficients are elements of the $X_i$ so they're in $\mathbb Q.$  As you go through your favorite algorithm for solving a system of linear equations, you never use any operations other than addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, so the coefficients always remain in $\mathbb Q,$ and you'll never get any solution with elements that are not in $\mathbb Q.$

So your guess is right.  The rank is the same.

**EDIT** Reading this over, I see that the argument only proves that the rank can't get any smaller.  I leave it to you to prove that the rank can't get any bigger. (Hint: This part is really easy.)

Comment: Do you mean a1X1 + a2X2+...+ arXr = 0 ? To prove that the rank can't get any bigger, we just need to say ℚ⊆ ℝ ⊆ ℂ right? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  A $\mathbb Q-$ linear combination is an $\mathbb R-$ linear combination is a $\mathbb C-$ linear combination.  If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so other people can see it's been taken care of.